# Changes not saved in PHP Script on Cpanel

Tags: php, cpanel

I am practicing some PHP Scripting on my Web Hosting. I Log into my CPanel, go to File Manager, create PHP Scripts and then test them in the browser.

Now, the problem is, the first time the script works Ok. However, if I make some changes, it keeps loading the previous output.

It is really difficult to debug this way.

I have tried clearing browser's cache, deleting the cookies, restarting browser, logging off and logging back in to Cpanel. However, nothing seems to work.

Even a simple code like:

```
<?php echo "Hello" ?>
```

won't work.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: yes, I give the real URL when I try to test it so that it is a fresh HTTP request to the Server everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try fileZilla software to connect ftp 
and be sure your file is correct
then try simple html file

Comment: Thanks. I use FileZilla now. Keep it connected via FTP to the CPanel, make changes to the code, delete previous file, upload new file and the changes are reflected instantly.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, it is caused by the Nginx caching.

Just go to the Cpanel home > Right sidebar > Nginx Caching > click on the button (Clear Cache).

[image]